# Eloquent ORM Laravel relations

Tags: mysql, orm, eloquent, database-relations

In Laravel, I have two tables:

*books* table has two fields( *id* , *name* )

*users* has three fields( *id* , *name*, *book_id* )

How I can get users that read more than five books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't as what you show us is one-to-many relationship, where many `User` belong to one `Book`. That being said, one user can have only one book related. What you want is probably many-to-many relationship with pivot table, like this:

```
users table: id, name
book_user pivot table: book_id, user_id
books table: id, name

// then relationships:

// User model
public function books()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('Book');
}

// Book model
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}

// and calling relations:
$user = User::first();

$user->books; // collection of Book models

// Now to fetch users that have more than 5 books related, what you asked:
User::has('books', '>', 5)->get(); // collection of User models
```